# How to change a HTML "select" element's contents in Ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

In a `PHP` file there are two HTML "select" elements , say list1 and list2. I want that on the `onChange` event of list1 then list2's contents ( display-text and value ) will change by using `Ajax` calling a `PHP` file. The content of list2 will be from a MySQL database table.  How to do that ?

Here what I tried :

```
<script language="javascript">
    function loadObjectsFromTypetache(typeTache)
    {
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {// code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                document.getElementById("obs_id_obj").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","ajaxRemplirObjetObsrv.php?type_tache="+typeTache,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
    function Annuler() 
    {
        // Retour à la liste des enregistrements
        document.location = "<?php echo PAGE_ADMIN; ?>?action=AdminGererObservation";
    }
</script>
...
<select id="typ_tache_code" name="typ_tache_code" onChange="loadObjectsFromTypetache(document.form.typ_tache_code.value)"> // this is list1
<option value="" ><?php echo _getText('admin.obsrv.selectionnerTypeTache'); ?></option>
<?php

   for ($u=0; $u < $data['listTypeTache']['cnt']; $u++)
   {
?>
<option value = "<?php echo $data['listTypeTache'][$u]['typ_tache_code']; ?>"><?php echo $data['listTypeTache'][$u]['typ_tache_lib']; ?></option>
<?php
   }
?>
</select>
<select id="obs_id_obj" name="obs_id_obj">... // this is list2
```

So what to write in the php url file called by ajax ?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: It's in the url page which will return the response that I have problem !

Comment: try `chained selects` jquery plugin: http://www.appelsiini.net/2010/jquery-chained-selects

Answer (score 0):

Tyr this

```
$('#select#s1').change(function(){
  $('select#s2').load('/url')
})
```

**/url** retrieves:

```
<option value="1">Second</option>
<option value="2">Second</option>
```